# Asp.Net MVC Can't get .html files or .xml files 404 error?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

How do I return .html files or .xml files that are in folders in the view? I'm using jquery which request a static Html file via ajax and insert the results into a div and it keeps giving a 404 error any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to ignore routing for a given path, use:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("path/to/static/content");
```

Also, I may be reading your question wrong, but it's a bad idea to put static content in your View folders.  Make a folder like "Content" or "public" at the document root.

If you're actually needing to *process* a request and spit it out as .html or .xml, make a route that looks like "{controller}/{action}/{id}.xml" or something.